# Chaining melt and groupby in pandas causes integer values to be cast to boolean

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to reshape the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': [True,False,False,True], 
    'id': [1,0,1,2]})
```

[image]

...to create a dataframe similar to the example below. Column names should now be the index, and the frequency of each unique value should be provided as a count.

[image]

Using melt and groupby almost achieves this, except that 0 and 1 (integers) are cast to False and True (boolean).

```
df.melt().groupby(['variable','value']).size().to_frame(name='freq')
```

[image]

Any suggestions for achieving the desired dataframe (without the 0 and 1 being cast to boolean) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Index with type object. Since you have bool and int , it will convert to object , and in pandas 0 treat as False 1 treat as True for object conversion .

Comment: makes sense, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dtype` convert `id` to `str`

```
df.id=df.id.astype(str)
df.melt().groupby(['variable','value']).size().to_frame(name='freq')
Out[81]: 
                freq
variable value      
feature  False     2
         True      2
id       0         1
         1         2
         2         1
```

Comment: This answers the question as it is phrased, but changing the data type to a string isn't ideal. e.g. df.id.sum() now returns '1012', rather than 4.

Comment: @tomp that is true